# Android from Navigation Drawer, call method in current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to simply call a function in the current fragment from the main activity drawer but cannot figure out a way to do it. I have a list of items in a RecyclerView on the drawer, when I click on one I want to load details into the current fragment. Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: What you need is using callback interfaces for listening to events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62126408/can-an-activity-access-a-fragment-to-know-if-a-button-has-been-pressed/62126540#62126540

Comment: That doesn't work because nav_host_fragment is always the fragment, not the home_fragment or the login_fragment, etc.

Comment: onAttachFragment is always NavHostFragment, not individual fragments...why???

Comment: you need to implement this on your individual fragments not the NavHostFragment. If you provide some code snippets I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the ViewModel approach and it made things much easier. Took a while to set up but was worth it.